# Joomla step-2 no database type to select

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am very new for Joomla. When I try to install it in my enviroment, in step 2, I am blocked because of database type to choose.
[image]

Obviously, no option to choose at all!!

However, in my window enviroment, there are 2 database: sqlserver&mysql.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any database drivers/modules available for php? Does `php -i | grep sql` spit out anything?

Comment: Thanks for response. I-x, could you please let me know more detail. Just now, I have gotten many results with php -i. However, 'grep sql' told me not a correct command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... sorry, forgive my silly question. In my enviroment, my sql has not been supported by PHP. That's the root